# How many GPUs Does Windows 7 Support?

Tags: windows-7, windows, gpu

With SLi and Without, I have been looking around online and cannot see any official answer from Microsoft or any forums.

I know for a fact windows 7 will run 7 GPUs without SLi alongside each other but unfortunately can't fit anymore into the box for testing.

how many GPUs could you use in one Super-Micro or box, running Windows 7 64bit.

And if it's 7+ What are the considerations besides power / heat that need to be accounted for?  or are they the only two main factors.

Comment: The bottleneck is available PCIe bandwidth. Because there’s barely enough for four graphics cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've found, it doesn't seem to be Windows that would be the limiting factor, rather the driver or cards. 32-bit Windows definitely has a limit (running out of addresses and all that), but it looks like 64-bit can handle enough cards that it would be almost impossible to reach a limit on the OS.

I did see that AMD cards can only work with up to 4 in a system, but people said NVIDIA had no problem with 8 GPUs at once. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=11677.0

Someone on [this forum thread](https://www.gpugrid.net/forum_thread.php?id=3281) suggested that NVIDIA does have an 8 card limit, but that it is built into the driver and is not a limitation of Windows.

From what I read, I'm going to say it depends more on hardware than the OS: how many slots you have; how powerful your CPU is; how much available bandwidth, etc. You might be able to run 16 without a complaint from Windows, but have issues with performance and bottenecking.

Comment: That Bitcoin forum is actually one i was reading through but found conflicting answers in regards to some having to be SLi and others not, thanks for the answer, I will look into the nvidia driver thing as they're the cards we primarily use.

Comment: Re driver limits: interesting. So you could add at least 4 AMD cards **and** 8 Nvidia cards **and** add some Matrox or others to just keep going?

Comment: @Hennes not sure. I've always had it where cross-branding like that makes it so none of the cards are happy. So maybe it works, but I think it'd be really unstable.

Comment: @Hennes and Zach, The driver limit i suspect is to prevent memory leaks or similar issues as well depending on what your using the GPUs for i'd imagine there could be conflicts, I'd love to see how many GPUs i could shove in a box just to test.

Comment: I have had systems with AMD and Nvidia cards. Simple because those two were the only cards available and and we needed something working without delay.  The two card setup was stable.