# Windows 7 not picking up 8th GPU

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

Adding on to a previous question I asked.
[How many GPUs Does Windows 7 Support?](https://superuser.com/questions/1094939/how-many-gpus-does-windows-7-support)

I have managed to stick 8 Nvidia GTX 980Tis into a Tyan Supermicro Box.
It's running Windows 7 Professional 64bit

It will be used for rendering, scenes created in Autodesk Maya 2016, submitted through Deadline 7.2 and Rendered With Redshift.

They were previously running Windows 10 but it was very unstable, kept crashing constantly so I wanted to test it on 7.

It works perfectly with 7 GPUs, Rendered 2000 frames overnight without a single issue, although it's not using the 8th GPU.

[image]

The GPU Is not faulty either, I tried replacing it with two working 980Tis and got the same problem with both.

This was a clean install of windows 7, all of the cards are running the same driver, I have uninstalled and re-installed but nothing.

From what I have found online, all of the solutions point to a driver issue, although I believe this might be a unique case considering the power I'm working with.

Again, the 8 GPUs worked on windows 10, so is it Windows 7? is 7 the maximum number of GPUs it can support?

Edit: Removing one GPU will cause Device manager to appear normal, you can remove any one GPU and the error will go away.

Edit: System Specs from Speccy

```
Operating System
    Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP1

CPU
    Intel Xeon E5 v3 @ 2.40GHz  40 °C
    Haswell-E/EP 22nm Technology
    Intel Xeon E5 v3 @ 2.40GHz  44 °C
    Haswell-E/EP 22nm Technology

RAM
    80.0GB Unknown @ 931MHz (13-13-13-31)

Motherboard
    TYAN FT77C-B7079 (SOCKET 0)

Graphics

    Standard Monitor (1024x768@60Hz)

    2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti (PNY)  77 °C

    2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti (PNY)  80 °C

    2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti (PNY)  78 °C

    2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti (PNY)  82 °C

    ASPEED Technology ASPEED Graphics Family(WDDM) (ASPEED Technology)

    2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti (PNY)  80 °C

    2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti (PNY)  82 °C

    2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti (PNY)  83 °C

    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti (PNY)

    ForceWare version: 368.39

    SLI Disabled <- This is on purpose

Storage
    238GB ATA Samsung SSD 850 SCSI Disk Device (SSD)    27 °C

Optical Drives
    No optical disk drives detected

Audio
    NVIDIA High Definition Audio
```

Any other info that might help just ask for it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41956/discussion-on-question-by-ryanig-windows-7-not-picking-up-8th-gpu).

Comment: which error code do you see in device manager?